# Extremely obscure bug related to hyperref, sections and labels - anyone knows what is going on? What can I do?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

First of all, I am sorry but I cannot provide a minimum working example because I have not been able to replicate it on a small scale and I cannot share the whole document;

The problem is the following: I get a warning

```
"Reference `fig:test3' on page 81 undefined on input line 1293."
```

```
"Reference `fig:test4' on page 81 undefined on input line 1293."
```

Now you would think that I just did not set a label but unfortunately, I did; The part where it happens is at the end of a chapter; There is a chapter afterwards where things work normally; Now comes the full extent of weirdness; I looked into the end of the chapter and it writes the following:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/test1.png}
        \caption[Test1]
        {Test1.}\label{fig:test1}
    \end{figure}
    
\begin{figure}[H]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/test2.png}
        \caption[Test2]
        {Test2.}\label{fig:test2}
    \end{figure}
    
\begin{figure}[H]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/test3.png}
        \caption[Test3]
        {Test3.}\label{fig:test3}
    \end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/test4.png}
        \caption[Test4]
        {Test4.}\label{fig:test4}
    \end{figure}
```

Now just out of curiosity, I switched pictures test1,test2 with test3 and test4 so I replaced the upper part with

```
\begin{figure}[H]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/test3.png}
        \caption[Test3]
        {Test3.}\label{fig:test3}
    \end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/test4.png}
        \caption[Test4]
        {Test4.}\label{fig:test4}
    \end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/test1.png}
        \caption[Test1]
        {Test1.}\label{fig:test1}
    \end{figure}
    
\begin{figure}[H]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/test2.png}
        \caption[Test2]
        {Test2.}\label{fig:test2}
    \end{figure}
```

and now the warning says

```
"Reference `fig:test1' on page 81 undefined on input line 1289."
```

```
"Reference `fig:test2' on page 81 undefined on input line 1289."
```

So basically it is not about the figure itself but just which figure is last; The one that is last has problems with the label; This is unfortunately a real error, i.e. in the text it says "Figures ?? and ?? in Section..." The Figures are printed normally but the reference doesn't work at all, e.g. they are also not listed in the "List of Figures"

It basically seems as it is the chapter is "too long" and it stops working at some point which does not make a lot of sense as it is just around 50 pages; I tried it on overleaf and texworks (both with pdflatex) and it is the same result; Even when I change the compiler it causes this problem;

I also for a moment thought f*** off, I am just going to switch the sections a bit so the section with the two pictures comes first but then I had an equation label at the end of the chapter which then was not recognized so the same warning happened but just with something different;

Anyone an idea what I can do? Some log that I could read? Anyone heard of a similar problem or knows where it could possibly come from?

Comment: are you using `\include`?

Comment: Yes, I do; Is that a problem?

Comment: It could. labels are written to the aux-file, but if your include closes that too early there is nothing where they can write to. Try a \clearpage after the figures (assuming that there are inside the \include.)

Comment: To be a bit more precise: I have a main.tex and each chapter is in a separate .tex file, where I use  \include{chap1.tex} and so on; However, I also thought that maybe the include has a limit so I took the chapter that causes problems and copied around half of it into a new .tex file and then used  \include{chap1part1.tex}  \include{chap1part2.tex} but the result is unchanged;

Comment: I put \clearpage right below the four figures but it did not do anything..And for the two people already downvoting my post, please explain why doing it; I really think this is unfair :-(

Comment: well sorry but you will have to make a complete example. Shorten as much as you can and then replace text by dummy text and \vspace commands and then show the example and the log.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I just copied the whole chapter into the main document and it worked, so thank you so so much!!!!!!!! You saved my day; One last question if you can answer it: Leaving the whole 2000 lines of code in the main.tex is somewhat ugly so do you know how I can still use \include or sth similar to not have the chapter in the main.tex? As I said, for some strange reason, splitting the chapter into two files and using two times \include did absolutely nothing; But if you do not know, no problem, you already saved my day

Comment: you can use \input instead of \include. And be aware that if something is wrong with \include in your document it can affect other, not to obvious code that write to files, e.g. the table of contents entries.

Comment: there is no practical limit on the size of an include file (and any file too big to include would be too big for the main document) so any problem you have is due to code you have not shown. possible causes: not running latex enough times, using `\includeonly`, having an unrelated error or `\endinput` that stops the end of the file being processed, .... You can _always_ make an example to include here. Start from a copy of your document you only need to show one `\label` and one `\ref` that fails, so you can delete all words and images, and then delete all packages not needed for the example

Comment: I do not have any errors, and no other warnings except "Package caption Warning: The option `hypcap=true' will be ignored for this particular \caption on input line 1059. See the caption package documentation for explanation." which however happens in another chapter; I am not sure what other problems I could possibly have given that if I just switch the figures test1 and test2 with test3 and test4 it fails me differently; But I read that \include is somewhat inferior to \input except for the speed boost because it messes with the aux file which then cause for one or another reason that error

Comment: \include is inferior to \input in the same way that a screwdriver is inferior to a hammer.  They're slightly different tools for slightly different situations.  If you use the wrong one, then it's inferior.  If you use the right one, then it's superior.

Comment: The main problem is likely to be `[H]`.

Comment: `\include{chap1part1.tex}` so there is your error most likely. Use `\include{chap1part1}` with no extension

Answer (score 2):

You have not shown any relevant code in the question but in a comment you say you used `\include{chap1part1.tex}`

Prior to 2020 this would not work (the documented use of `\include` omits the `.tex` extension). It does work in an updated texlive 2020 or texlive 2021 onwards.

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\include{chap1part1.tex}

See \ref{foo}

\end{document}
```

**chap1part1.tex**

```
\section{wibble}\label{foo}
```

Produces

[image]

in a current latex, but in texlive 2019 it produces

[image]

with log warnings

```
No file chap1part1.tex.tex.

LaTeX Warning: Reference `foo' on page 1 undefined on input line 7.
```

Comment: Hi David, thank you very much for your answer. I was curious about it and tried to use \include{chap1} instead of \include{chap1.tex} and the error is still there; Only really replacing it with \input{chap1} solves the problem; I still have no idea why this is; In this chapter I have like 300 labels and all work fine except for the last ones, it is really odd but I feel like include somehow screws it up with the aux file

Comment: @Ivan No.  `\include` has been used in literally millions of documents  without breaking `\ref`. You have something _in your document_ that is breaking it. As I noted under your question, you can provide an example then you could get a more specific answer